# how to set id for every node in a angular material tree view, in order that every node is independent

Tags: angular-material, treeview

I can I set node id for every node in a angular material tree view, in order that every node is independent.

the HTML code looks like this:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
     <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
            <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="locationField"/>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
              <mat-option *ngFor="let filteredFieldResult of locationFieldResults" [value]="filteredFieldResult">
                {{filteredFieldResult}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.item}}

  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
<button (click)="addNode()">Add Node</button>
<button (click)="addSubNode()">Add SubNode</button>
<button (click)="changeNode()">Change Node</button>
```

Comment: Can you expand more on what you mean by independent?

Comment: I think he means that he would like to differentiate the nodes by ids, so he can manipulate them more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can include that id into the structure of the node you are creating.

example:

```
export class MyFlatNode{
   constructor(public name: string, public level = 1, public expandable = false, public loadMoreParentItem: string | null = null, public id:number = 0, public parentId: number=0) {}
}
```

and while creating the node for the tree, I used the following code in the transformer method given by material angular.

```
newNode = new MyFlatNode(node.name, node.level, node.hasChildren, null, node.id, node.parentId);
```

As you can see above, that I have passed all the information like node name, node level and node id etc. you can pass any information that you would possibly need in your tree nodes.

You can also do the same for the nested tree node by using the appropriate class constructor.